# Help for a translation

Tags: subordinate-clauses, reading-comprehension

I'm reading Install from Risa Wataya and right from the start, there's a sentence I had to read many many times before I could make any sense out of it:

> 「バカだねみんなと同じ生活が嫌なんて一体自分をどれだけ特別だと思ってるんだ努力もせず時間だけそんな惜しんで、大体あんたにゃ人生の目標がない、だからそう、うだうだと他の何百人もの人間が乗り越えてきた基本的でありきたりな悩みをひきずってんのさ。」

Here's my (poor) attempt at a translation:

> Isn't it stupid? Not wanting to live the same life as everyone else. With time you'll regret not putting any effort in thinking about how much you're special/different. First off, there's no goal in your life if you're not part of it(?). That's why you're having to drag the basic (?) and common trouble of surpassing hundreds of people.

I feel about 0% confident in that translation, especially because of all those subclauses. Did I get some of it right? ^^

Thanks!

EDIT: 
Here's my attempt to add punctuation:

> 「バカだね。みんなと同じ生活が嫌なんて。一体、自分をどれだけ特別だと思ってるんだ努力もせず、時間だけそんな惜しんで（す）。大体あんたにゃ人生の目標がない。だからそう、うだうだと（他の何百人もの人間が乗り越えてきた基本的でありきたりな悩みを）ひきずってんのさ。」

I'm assuming that's incorrect? ^^;

Comment: That looks like a pure guesslation; It is just way off, I am sorry to say.  It contains a couple of really serious and several small mistakes.   I would recommend that you start by forcefully placing punctuations into the original so as to break it into several sentences.  That should help you at least analyze the passage a little better if nothing else.

Comment: ouch lol ok... but that's the point I guess, I don't know how to parse it. I'll try adding punctuation and add it to the question.

Comment: done... where am I wrong? :P

Comment: Maybe the sentence should end after　ー思ってるんだ？That was my first guess but then the rest of the sentence doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: Not sure why this was put off-topic, I did put prior effort and showed my tentative translation. I agree it's not the best "question" there is, since there's no specific grammar point involved and it's not especially useful to anyone else, but I didn't think it would break the rule (I did see many translation requests that were first closed, than re-opened after some effort of the OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the author punctuated in such a strange way, but I'd say you're  70% correct. Split the passage into five sentences as follows:

> - バカだね、みんなと同じ生活が嫌なんて。
> - 一体自分をどれだけ特別だと思ってるんだ。
>     How special do you think you are?
> - 努力もせず時間だけそんな惜しんで。
>     (You're) Just grudging time, even though you're making no effort.
> - 大体あんたにゃ人生の目標がない。
> - だからそう、うだうだと、[[他の何百人もの人間が乗り越えてきた]基本的でありきたりな悩み]をひきずってんのさ。
>     So that's why you're being bothered by [the basic and common trouble [hundreds of other people have already overcome]].

- The third sentence ends with で/て just because いる is omitted after it. (It's not a request)
- 時間を惜しむ = to grudge/value time
- 他の人が乗り越えてきた悩み = trouble which other people have (already) overcome

Comment: Oh... Thanks! That third sentence was quite problematic for me. Without knowing that で　=　でいる here, I felt it couldn't really be a sentence on its own. 
And yes of course, it's _the people_ who _overcame_, they're marked with が not を！ Oops. Thanks a lot! I would have had the wrong assumptions about this character ^^;